# Why these type family instances conflicting?

Tags: haskell, type-families

I'm using GHC-8.0.1. This code (requires the [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) lib):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies            #-}       
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts        #-}           
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds         #-}

module Bug where

import Data.Kind
import Data.Singletons

type family MkCtx (kx :: Type) (kc :: Type) (c :: kc) (x :: kx) :: Constraint
type instance MkCtx kx (kx ~> Constraint) c x = Apply c x
type instance MkCtx kx (kx -> Constraint) c x = c x
```

with message:

```
Conflicting family instance declarations:
      forall kx (x :: kx) (c :: kx ~> Constraint).
        MkCtx kx (kx ~> Constraint) c x = Apply c x
      forall kx (x :: kx) (c :: kx -> Constraint).
        MkCtx kx (kx -> Constraint) c x = c x
```

Why GHC considers these instances conflicting? 
I don't see how they overlap.

**UPDATE:** Confirmed GHC bug https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13931

Comment: If we take `(~>) = (->)` they unify -- I think `~>` is handled as any other type variable of kind `*->*->*`.

Comment: @chi `~>` isn't parsed as a type variable; removing the `singletons` import causes a scope error. `kx ~> Constraint` is a type synonym which expands to `TyFun kx Constraint -> *`. There is no way to unify `.. -> *` and `.. -> Constraint` so I think it should work; indeed if you replace `Constraint` with any other type (except `*`) it does work - so I think it's indeed a bug. Back in the day `*` and `Constraint` were the same type, so I'm guessing some part of the typechecker still believes that?

Comment: This is totally off topic, but `TypeInType` implies both `DataKinds` and (via `PolyKinds`) `KindSignatures`, so you can cut two lines of boilerplate.

Comment: As for the actual point, I'm pretty sure `Constraint` and `*` are still the same in Core, and therefore also for type families. The GHC devs are working on fixing that, but it proved complicated, so I think they put it off till 8.4.

Comment: See https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/32